# Recarregar automaticamente a página em determinado horário

Tags: javascript

Preciso de um código para web (Wordpress) que force o reload de apenas a página inicial do site em um determinado horário, isto para com todos os usuários, por exemplo ás 18:10hs

Comment: tu consegue usar uma extensão do chrome, mas não em horário, ele recarrega de minutos em minutos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente o Javascript abaixo:

```
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds) {
var now = new Date();
var then = new Date();

if(now.getHours() > hours ||
   (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) ||
    now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >= seconds) {
    then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
}
then.setHours(hours);
then.setMinutes(minutes);
then.setSeconds(seconds);

var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, timeout);
```